# .bat start up script hanging after opening first executable

Tags: batch-file, command-line

So I have started to write a .bat script to control the start up of my work laptop.

This is what I have so far:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\
Chrome.exe www.google.com www.google.co.uk www.google.it
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\
outlook.exe
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-x64\sqldeveloper\
sqldeveloper.exe
exit
```

I have tried this in command prompt and it does exactly what I expect, however I run the batch file and it opens up chrome with the 3 tabs, then the console just seems to hang there is no flashing cursor. I was expecting this to just carry onto the next line. I assume I am missing something but a quick google has proved useless.

Hoping someone can shine some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to `start` the executable for the batch to continue to the next command without waiting for the executable to terminate.

```
start "Window title for Chrome" Chrome.exe ...
```

for instance.

Comment: Cheers! I did notice just before you posted it that if I closed each window it would then open the not executable. With your help it is now all fixed.